# C#: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (104): Connection reset by peer

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to connect over SSH to a server. The code works on one server, but not the second, failing with the below exception. I've tested `ssh user@host` via the CLI using the same key and it works fine on both.

Error:

```
Unhandled exception. Renci.SshNet.Common.SshConnectionException: Connection reset by peer
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (104): Connection reset by peer
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at Renci.SshNet.Abstractions.SocketAbstraction.Read(Socket socket, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Renci.SshNet.Session.TrySocketRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 length)
   at Renci.SshNet.Session.ReceiveMessage()
   at Renci.SshNet.Session.MessageListener()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Renci.SshNet.Session.WaitOnHandle(WaitHandle waitHandle, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Renci.SshNet.Session.WaitOnHandle(WaitHandle waitHandle)
   at Renci.SshNet.Session.Connect()
   at Renci.SshNet.BaseClient.CreateAndConnectSession()
   at Renci.SshNet.BaseClient.Connect()
```

I'm using SSH.NET

```
var keyStr = File.ReadAllText("/home/me/.ssh/id_rsa");

PrivateKeyFile privateKey = null;

using (var keystrm = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(keyStr)))
{
     privateKey = new PrivateKeyFile(keystrm);
}

var keyFiles = new[] { privateKey };


var methods = new List<AuthenticationMethod>();
methods.Add(new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod("me", keyFiles));

var con = new ConnectionInfo("...", 22, "root", methods.ToArray());

using var sshClient = new SshClient(con);
sshClient.Connect();
```

Comment: Is it a carriage return issue?  See : https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/releases/tag/2020.0.1

Comment: any update? I think ms server and all microsoft tools should not be used in modern companies that use linux